# Read The Data From DropDown in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am doing the ASP.net MVC 3 (Empty type and not the internet type) with the Database First approach...

What i need is

Step 1:
I just used the dropdown to display the various locations where the company is located. The list comes from the Organization table and Location is only one string field in this Oranization Table,

Step 2:
While the user is doing registration, the dropdown list will show the locations.. Now, user selects India, then this value (Location Name) should store in the UserLogin Table...

Now how to read the value from the dropdown and i hope you understand my question and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some code that you've tried?  If you have a strongly typed view then when you create the drop downlist with `@Html.DropDownListFor()` (if I remember correctly) it will handle passing the value back the the controller used when posting the data.

Comment: // In my Signup Control i wrote like this

       public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.OLocation = new SelectList(dbcontext.Organization_Details, "OName", "OLocation");
            return View();
        }


// and in its view, i wrote like this...


//and This View is strongly typed with "UserLogin" View Model 

        // Previous Code Part
        @Html.Dropdownlist("OLocation")

Comment: Hai any no comments or Reply till now.....

Answer (score 2):

I would use view models:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller action that will serve the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new RegisterViewModel();
    model.Locations = new SelectList(dbcontext.Organization_Details, "OName", "OLocation");
    return View(model);
}
```

then the corresponding strongly typed view:

```
@model RegisterViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LocationName)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LocationName, Model.Locations)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and finally the controller action that will be invoked when the form is submitted:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    // model.LocationName will contain the selected location here
    ...
}
```